# How to use Cron to regulate & schedule data and network usage

Tags: ubuntu, networking, cron

I have recently built up a RPi cluster to work on BOINC but I felt it was using up too much internet. So I set up a cron job like this:

```
5 0 * * * nmcli networking on
0 5 * * * nmcli networking off
```

The problem now is that I am unable to work on the cluster at any other time. Is there a different way to approach this problem? Possibly something like:

1. Can I make RPi accessible from a single IP, while blocking it from internet?
2. Use Crontab to use the networking to turn-off when a particular data usage [say, 100MB per node] is reached?

Specs: Rpi is running Ubuntu Server. I am using Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add couple of points which I came across later:

1. This is possible using the subnets. But I did not apply as i found such is not useful. See 2.
2. Since I found that I could regulate the transfer using BOINC itself, I did not need to do the `nmcli` or `subnets`.

We can regulate the bandwidth and data usage using the preferences like [this](https://boinc.berkeley.edu/wiki/Preferences) and [this](https://boinc.berkeley.edu/wiki/PreferencesXml).